# how do I call a method that contains an exception handler

Tags: java, android, exception

When I have a method like this:

```
public XmlParser() throws XmlPullParserException, IOException
{
  ...do some stuff...
}
```

How do I call that method?

I tried doing this:

```
XmlParser xmlparse = new XmlParser();
```

but I get an **Unhandled exception type IOException** error.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the constructor for `XmlParser` declares that it `throws XmlPullParserException, IOException`, then you need to do one of the following things in your code.

Your first option is to catch those Exceptions directly in your code:

```
XmlParser xmlparse;

try {
    xmlparse = new XmlParser();
} catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
    // handle...
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle...
}
```

Alternately, you could declare whichever method you're including this code in such that it also `throws XmlPullParserException, IOException`.

Finally, you could catch one of the exceptions and pass the other one on.  Let's assume that you're writing `myMethod`:

```
public void myMethod() throws IOException {
    XmlParser xmlparse;

    try {
        xmlparse = new XmlParser();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        // handle...
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the 1st option and I get an error highlighting the "e" that says 'duplicate field exception'.  I guess because it sees 2 "e"'s?

Comment: I don't think that's the case; each `e` should be specific to the enclosing block...Unless you have another local variable declared named `e` outside the try/catch.  Either way, the code above is untested, but should be close-enough to get you to where you need to go...

Answer (score 3):

Either use a `try/catch` block or `throws` clause.

`try/catch` if you want to handle it:

```
try {
    XmlParser xmlparse = new XmlParser();
} catch(XmlPullParserException ex) {
    // handler code
} catch(IOException ex) {
    // handler code
}
```

`throws` if you are doing that inside a method and want the caller of the method to handle it:

```
public void yourMethod() throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {

    XmlParser xmlparse = new XmlParser();
    //...
```

Answer (score 1):

You surround it with try catch:

```
try{
XmlParser xmlparse = new XmlParser();
} catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
} catch (IOException) {
}
```

Don't forget to handle exceptions correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure to catch the exceptions:

```
....
try {
    XmlParser xmlparse = new XmlParser();
} catch (XmlPuillParserException e) {
    // do something
} catch (IOException e) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try{
    XmlParser xmlparse = new XmlParser();
}catch(XmlPuillParserException e){
    //do something useful
}
catch(IOException e){
    //do something useful
}
```

Or, instead of IOException and XmlPuillParserException, you can use Exception, but it's bad style